# Inverting a test to find lower confidence interval

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, confidence-interval

I'm trying to come up with how to invert a hypothesis test to obtain a lower confidence bound, specifically for a binomial distribution. So suppose you have a binomial distribution with 5 trials, and 4 successes, and you want to obtain a lower confidence interval, of say 95%.

Typically the way I've previously learned would be to just use the normal approximation, and find the critical value.
However, to do this we typically require that  $n\hat{p}\geq5$ and $n(1-\hat{p})\geq 5$,
so for the observed proportion of $4/5$, we cannot proceed in this manner.

So how should one go about inverting a hypothesis test here?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that a normal approximation would not be reliable for the specific outcome you mention.

Something like this may have been implemented in the
`binom.test` procedure in R. [If a hypothetical
value is not entered, then $p_0 = 0.5$ is assumed.]

First, get the CI corresponding to 4 successes in 5 trials:

```
binom.test(4, 5, alt="g")

        Exact binomial test

data:  4 and 5
number of successes = 4, number of trials = 5,
 p-value = 0.1875
alternative hypothesis: 
 true probability of success is greater than 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3425917 1.0000000
 sample estimates:
probability of success 
                   0.8
```

Then verify that using the bound of the CI to specify the null hypothesis, puts you at the edge of the non-rejection region.

```
binom.test(4, 5, p=.3426, alt="g")

        Exact binomial test

data:  4 and 5
number of successes = 4, number of trials = 5,
 p-value = 0.05

alternative hypothesis: 
 true probability of success is greater than 
 0.3426
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3425917 1.0000000
sample estimates:
 probability of success 
                    0.8
```

Because of the discreteness of the binomial distribution and the particulars of the style
of CI implemented, you need to be careful
about definitions. Please read the documentation
of `binom.test` to see if it really does what
you have in mind. Especially:

```
Details

Confidence intervals are obtained by a 
procedure first given in Clopper and Pearson 
(1934). This guarantees that the confidence 
level is at least 'conf.level', but in general 
does not give the shortest-length confidence 
intervals.
```

Also, the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) on CIs for binomial proportions may be useful--especially, the section on Clopper-Pearson CIs.